# Rest Assured: Isn't there a better way to test an array of results?

Tags: rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am studying Rest Assured framework now.

Using some API I get the following (partial) JSON response:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "type": "AAAA"
        },
        {
            "type": "A"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to verify the types.
The only way I found so far is to use gson to translate the string to an object and then assert:

```
@Given("^test2$")
public void test2$() {

    RestAssured.baseURI = BASE_URI;

    String response =
            given()
            .param(KEY_KEY, API_KEY)
            .param(URL_KEY, URL_TO_CHECK)
            .when()
            .get(RESOURCE)
            .asString();

    System.out.println(response);

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.setPrettyPrinting();
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    WhtResponse whtResponse = gson.fromJson(response, WhtResponse.class);

    assertTrue(whtResponse.getResults().size() == 2);
    assertTrue(whtResponse.getResults().get(0).getType().equals("AAAA"));
    assertTrue(whtResponse.getResults().get(1).getType().equals("A"));
}
```

Please ignore that there are several asserts in one test method. I know it is not best practice but I am just "playing" now to study the material.

Is there a better, shorter, more fluent way to test both values? Maybe directly with Rest Assured and without the Gson?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a few ways but I want to present a specific one, using only `RestAssured`.

First, of all, you can create Java classes to represent the given JSON. You can always expand it.

Create a class `ResultsObject` (name doesn't matter)

```
public class ResultsObject {
    public List<TypeObject> results;
}
```

We are declaring that `RestAssured` have to look for a JSON Array of JSON Objects. Each of these Object is parsed to `TypeObject` (this name also doesn't matter). What matters, is the `results` variable name. It matches the `results` in the JSON.

So, now we have to create `TypeObject` class to represent each of JSON Objects.

```
public class TypeObject {
    public String type;
}
```

Again, the class name doesn't matter, what matters is `type` variable name. Just like in JSON.

Now, with a **single line of code** we can parse the JSON (either from `Response` or `String`) to the classes we created like this:

`ResultsObject results = response.jsonPath().get("$", ResultObject.class);`

Further work requires to create an assertion.

```
MatcherAssert.assertThat(types, Matchers.hasItems("AAAA", "A")); //you can use static imports if you'd like.
```

The assertion is from `Hamcrest` which is already included in `RestAssured`. It matches the Array of Strings to an Array of Strings of our choice.

You can notice, that `types` is not yet initialized. We need an Array of Strings but it's an Array of `TypeObject`. We can simply convert it using `Java Stream API` like this:

```
List<String> types = resultsObject.results.stream().map(x -> x.type).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And that's it!

But the way, if you get the Exception like this `Cannot deserialize object because no JSON deserializer found in classpath. Please put either Jackson (Databind) or Gson in the classpath.` all you have to do is add `jackson-databind` to Maven. Rest Assured is able to use `Gson` or `Jackson` databind to transform JSON into Java classes. 
All you need is the dependency, and you are all set.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

I already tested the solution.
It also gives you the flexibility of how you want to process the data, and as you can see, I used only 1 Assertion to compare all of the `type`s from JSON.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @dushkin No problem. Let me know if it worked how you wanted :) Remember that in the method `getObject` I inserted `$` as a root. If `results` array is under, for example `query.data` then you'd have to change `$` to `query.data` and it will work :)